# C recursively build tree using structure pointer

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, tree, structure

I'm now implementing [Barnes-Hut Algorithms](http://arborjs.org/docs/barnes-hut) for simulating N-body problem. I only want to ask about the building-tree part.

There are two functions I made to build the tree for it.

I recursively build the tree, and print the data of each node while building and everything seems correct, but when the program is back to the main function only the root of the tree and the child of the root stores the value. Other nodes' values are not stored, which is weird since I printed them during the recursion and they should have been stored.

Here's some part of the code with modification, which I thought where the problem might be in:

```
#include<...>
typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *child1,*child2;
}Node;
Node root; // a global variable
int main(){
    .
    set_root_and_build(); // is called not only once cuz it's actually in a loop
    traverse(&root);
    .
}
```

Here's the function set_root_and_build():

I've set the child pointers to NULL, but didn't show it at first.

```
void set_root_and_build(){
    root.data = ...;
    ..// set child1 and child2 =NULL;
    build(&root,...); // ... part are values of data for it's child 
}
```

And build:

```
void build(Node *n,...){
    Node *new1, *new2 ;
    new1 = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    new2 = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    ... // (set data of new1 and new2 **,also their children are set NULL**)
    if(some condition holds for child1){ // else no link, so n->child1 should be NULL
        build(new1,...);
        n->child1 = new1;
        //for debugging, print data of n->child1 & and->child2
    }
    if(some condition holds for child2){ // else no link, so n->child2 should be NULL
        build(new2,...);
        n->child1 = new2;
        //for debugging, print data of n->child1 & and->child2
    }
}
```

Nodes in the tree may have 1~2 children, not all have 2 children here.

The program prints out the correct data when it's in `build()` function recursion, but when it is back to main function and calls `traverse()`, it fails due to a segmentation fault.

I tried to print everything in `traverse()` and found that only the root, and root.child1, root.child2 stores the value just as what I've mentioned.

Since I have to called `build()` several times, and even in parallel, new1 and new2 can't be defined as global variables. (but I don't think they cause the problem here).

Does anyone know where it goes wrong?

The traverse part with debugging info:

```
void traverse(Node n){
    ...//print out data of n
    if(n.child1!=NULL)
        traverse(*(n.child1))
    ...//same for child2
}
```

Comment: This should be tagged C, not C++

Comment: Yes  `malloc()` is C and not C++

Comment: Thanks you guys, I'll change the tag.
but my code is .cpp file, is it still ok if I use malloc like this?

Comment: Can you post the traverse() code please

Comment: it's a bad practice to use `malloc()` in cpp.  You coud use `new1=new Node;` instead

Comment: @Christophe okay thanks a lot, I'll get rid of this bad habit :)

Comment: Yes !  You have now two solutions:  a standard C one (malloc) and a standard c++ one (new).  Up to you to choose.  I think you can therefore put the two tags C and C++.

Comment: "Since I have to called build( ) several times, and **even in parallel**" What exactly do you mean by that bolded bit???

Comment: I haven't did this in parallel yet, I mentioned it cuz I thought someone might suggest me set new1 and new2 to be global variables, which cause some problem if later I modify this  in parallel.

Comment: Ok, but the fact that your root Node is global will yield the same problem though.

Comment: I'll only run the set-data part of build( ) in parallel, so it would be okay :). And that's why the root's data is set in a different function.

Answer (score 2):

You may not be properly setting the children of `n` when the condition does not hold.  You might want this instead:

```
void set_root_and_build()
{
    root.data = ...;
    build(&root,...); // ... part are values of data for it's child 
}

void build(Node *n,...)
{
    n->child1 = n->child2 = NULL;

    Node *new1, *new2;
    new1 = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    new2 = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));

    // set data of new1 and new2 somehow (read from stdin?)

    if (some condition holds for new1) 
    {
        n->child1 = new1;
        build(n->child1,...);
        //for debugging, print data of n->child1
    }
    else
      free(new1);  // or whatever else you need to do to reclaim new1

    if (some condition holds for new2)
    {
        n->child2 = new2; 
        build(n->child2,...);
        //for debugging, print data of n->child2
    }
    else
      free(new2);  // or whatever else you need to do to reclaim new2
}
```

Of course, you should be checking the return values of malloc() and handling errors too.

Also, your traversal is a bit strange as it recurses by copy rather than reference.  Do you have a good reason for doing that?  If not, then maybe you want:

```
void traverse(Node *n)
{
    ...//print out data of n
    if (n->child1 != NULL)
        traverse(n->child1)
    ...//same for child2
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did set default value for each new node.
You're right, I always allocate two child nodes, but not ensure that it should be kept in the tree. But I think that would be okay...

As for the malloc, I do print the data in it so I think it worked.

Comment: @cshushu That's good, but you don't link your children to their parent unconditionally.  In your code, move the n->child1 = new1; and n->child2 = new2; outside of the if (condition).

Comment: Not all nodes have 2 children, I'm sorry that I didn't show what I actually mean , I've edit the code and add the comment.

Comment: What should happen to children when their condition does not hold?  Are you free'ing them as they will be lost / leak otherwise?

Comment: I just left it and didn't link it to any node, I modified it so that they're freed , but didn't change anything :(

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your tree traversal is that you certainly process the tree until you find a node pointer which is NULL.

Unfortunately when you create the nodes, these are not initialized neither with `malloc()` nor with `new` (it would be initialized with `calloc()` but this practice in cpp code is as bad as `malloc()`).  So your traversal continues to loop/recurse in the neverland of random pointers.

I propose you to take benefit of cpp and change slightly your structure to:

```
struct Node {   // that's C++:  no need for typedef
    int data;
    struct node *child1,*child2;
    Node() : data(0), child1(nullptr), child2(nullptr) {} // Makes sure that every created are first initalized
};
```

And later get rid of your old mallocs. And structure the code to avoid unnecessary allocations:

```
if(some condition holds for child1){ // else no link, so n->child1 should be NULL
    new1=new Node; // if you init it here, no need to free in an else !!
    build(new1,...);
    n->child1 = new1;
    ...
}
if (... child2) { ... }
```

Be aware however that poitners allocated with `new` should be released with `delete` and note with `free()`.

**Edit:**  There is a mismatch in your code snippet:

```
traverse(&root);  // you send here a Node* 

void traverse(Node n){  // but your function defines an argument by value !
   ...
}
```

Check that you didn't overllok some warnings from the compiler, and that you have no abusive cast in your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just tried the C++ one minutes ago, but the result is the same.

Comment: I've edited my answer.  Can you check your compiler messages as suggested ?